# How do I mark a given PHP CLI window as "urgent"/"attention required"?

Tags: php, windows, cmd, windows-10

I'm trying to make one of my PHP CLI scripts start "blinking" like Taskbar icons can do in modern Windows when they "require attention" or "are urgent". Basically the next best thing after force-focusing a window to the top.

I've tried everything related to outputting an "ASCII bell". It never does anything, not even a beep, on my Windows. Maybe that ASCII bell char causes this behaviour elsewhere, but it certainly doesn't do this on Windows.

What is the correct way to do this? Is it even possible? I'm amazed every day by just how few things can actually be done in practice.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 64-bit. PHP 5

Ring the bell. The first time you do it there is a ~1 second delay.

```
<?PHP
  echo Shell_Exec ('powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -NoProfile -Command "[console]::beep(750, 750) "');
?>
```

in powershell:

[console]::beep(750, 750)

in cmd:

START "" /min "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" %windir%\media\chimes.wav

from Run:

"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" %windir%\media\chimes.wav